# How to serve ONLY extensionless PHP files on nginx and add a trailing slash

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I am running nginx/1.18.0 with WordPress installed on my main website, but I also have a separate directory "services" that contains PHP files that I would like to serve only in the extensionless version, and also add a trailing slash.

So far I have succeeded in serving the extensionless PHP files, *but* the PHP version is still available if you navigate to it, and no trailing slash is added.

Here is my full configuration below.

```
server {
    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    access_log /var/www/example.com/logs/access.log;
    error_log /var/www/example.com/logs/error.log;
    rewrite_log on;

    root /var/www/example.com/public/;
    index index.php;

    location /services {
        try_files $uri $uri.html $uri/ @extensionless-php;
        rewrite ^(/.*)\.php(\?.*)?$ $1$2 permanent;
        rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 permanent;
    }

    location @extensionless-php {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ $1.php last;
        return                    301 $uri/;
    }

    location / {
         try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    # FastCGI
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param HTTPS on;
        fastcgi_param HTTP_SCHEME https;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 150;
    }
}
```

I read the following three articles to come up with this configuration:

- *[Remove HTML extension and trailing slash in nginx config](https://cobwwweb.com/remove-html-extension-and-trailing-slash-in-nginx-config)*
- *[NginX - Add trailing slash with 301 redirect without if statements](https://www.ateamsystems.com/tech-blog/nginx-add-trailing-slash-with-301-redirect-without-if-statements/)*
- *[Hide or remove .php or .html file extension in Nginx](https://nginx.tutorials24x7.com/blog/hide-or-remove-php-or-html-file-extension-in-nginx)*

There aren't any errors or notices in the error log either, so I'm sure if I've just managed to mingle up the rules here. How can I correct it?

Comment: Am I understand correctly that you want the following: 1) all the `/services/some/path` requests redirected to `/services/some/path/`; 2) all the `/services/some/path.php` requests redirected to `/services/some/path/`; 3) all the `/services/some/path/` requests served with `/services/some/path.php` script if that script exists, otherwise giving an HTTP 404 error?

Comment: Yes, you understand correctly. Sorry I was no clearer with my question, but you have worded it perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one instead of `location /services { ... }` and `location @extensionless-php { ... }`:

```
...
root /var/www/example.com/public; # remove the trailing slash!
index index.php;

location ^~ /services/ {

    # redirect '/services/some/path.php' to '/services/some/path/'
    location ~ \.php$ {
        rewrite ^(.*)\.php$ $1/ permanent;
    }

    # process the '/services/some/path' request (without the trailing slash)
    # this request cannot end with 'php' (that requests captured earlier),
    # but it can be a request for some existing assets file (.js, .css, image etc.)
    location ~ [^/]$ {
        # if '/services/some/path' isn't an existing file,
        # redirect the request to '/services/some/path/'
        if (!-f $document_root$uri) {
            rewrite ^ $uri/ permanent;
        }
    }

    # process the '/services/some/path/' request
    location ~ ^(.*)/$ {

        # try '/services/some/path.php' file
        set $script $document_root$1.php;

        # but if the '/services/some/path' is a directory,
        # try '/services/some/path/index.php' file instead
        if (-d $document_root$1) {
            set $script $document_root$1/index.php;
        }

        # return 404 if the file does not exists
        if (!-f $script) {
            return 404;
        }

        # handle the file with the PHP-FPM
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $script;

        # most likely these two doesn't needed for '/services/'
        # (needed for WordPress only) and can be safely removed
        fastcgi_param HTTPS on;
        fastcgi_param HTTP_SCHEME https;

        fastcgi_read_timeout 150;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
    }

}
...
```

Yes, it looks somewhat complicated, just like your requirements. Note that you need a separate PHP handler for that one, that's because you don't want to serve the `/.../file.php` URIs but to redirect them.

Leave the other two locations (that should serve the WordPress) unchanged.

Comment: Wow, this is great. It is almost working as expected. However, I'm now getting 404 now unfortunately. An error is produced in the log that says error] 11319#11319: *30 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream, client: ip address, server: example.com, request: "GET /services/some/path/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock:", host: "example.com" –

Comment: You mean some assets files like js/css/images etc? Do you remove a trailing slash from the root path?

Comment: PHP files. They are actually the only files in this directory. Yes, I removed the trailing slash from the root path as well.

Comment: Ok, I'll give it a test to check what happened. Are all those files located in the `/var/www/example.com/public/services` directory?

Comment: Thank you for your assitance. Yes, all the files are located in `/var/www/example.com/public/services` directory.

Comment: Just tested this config, everything is worked as expected. Created a `services/route.php` file with the `<?php echo "route"; ?>` content, request to `/services/route/` gives me the `route` response. Do you have any other sites configured within the same nginx instance? Any chances this configuration can somehow interfere with the others?

Comment: Slightly simplified the config removing `$path` and `$file` variables. Try this one, if it doesn't help, try renaming `$script` variable to something else, e.g. `$myscript`.

Comment: The latest config you posted works perfectly! Thank you so much for your help, Ivan. I appreciate you taking the time to explain it all not only in detail, but also taking the time to help me figure out the issue. I sincerely appreciate all your help.